# Drupal 9 custom module - button not rendering

Tags: html, css

I am working on my first Drupal 9/10 custom block module. This code does not render a button:

```
<div class="score-container">
  <span class="score">Score: <span id="score"></span></span>
  <button type="submit" "class="reset-button">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I already tried using type input and the original  tags. Other HTML and CSS in the code renders, so I'm confused.  I see the label rendered as text but that's it.  Here's the CSS that supposed to apply to it:

```
.reset-button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10% / 50%;
}

.reset-button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

When I look at the CSS in the inspector I don't see the button tags getting applied.  All I see is " Reset "

Thanks for your time and thoughts.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your hrml is getting filtered, but we need how you are outputting the html.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I just learned the hard way this site doesn't make it easy to follow up with anything more than short comments so I've posted a zip fiile of the entire module code here:   https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhpAOl_zhCibiim76QarbmWu_em0

Comment: The src/Plugin/Block/Myrisk.php file is where the HTML gets rendered

Comment: post the content of the module files.... I am not going to download a zip file

Comment: I posted the files in Github.  https://github.com/GuyManDude/Drupal9-Risk-Module

If you wanted to assemble them into a module you can install onto a Drupal 9/10 site, you can create a folder called myrisk with the following structure:


myrisk.info.yml
myrisk.libraries.yml
css/myrisk.css
js/myrisk.js
src/Plugin/Block/myrisk.php

the folder paths are case sensitive.

Comment: You can also see how this tool looks and functions in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/fwells11/pen/OJBPNbZ

I originally built this tool as a Drupal 7 block using the custom block method, but I could not do it in D9 ,so I decided to try and create a module with a block instead.

Comment: `<button type="submit" "class="reset-button">Reset</button>` - You have a rogue `"`

Comment: DarkBee's comment above will probably fix it. But while I am here I'll point out a couple of other things. Why have you got 2 libraries? you can put both css and js into a single library. Your JS depends on jquery, so you'll want to make that a dependancy in your library, Or rewrite the JS to not use jquery, which would be my reference. In your JS you set styles, would it not be better to add a class and style that in your css? Instead of putting the html in the PHP, I would probably register a theme and use a twig file.

Comment: OP is already using `twig`, I edited the tag out because the question has nothing to do with twig per se

Comment: That rogue " was just in the description.  My code is correct ie:
<button type="submit" class="reset-button">Reset</button>

@2pha  Drupal 9 has Jquery built-in to it.   I used GPT to create the code  ( I am no coder ) and this is what it came up with.

Comment: although jquery is built in, it is only included in pages if some other library depends on it. Most pages will probably have another library that includes jquery, but adding as a dependancy for your library makes sure. @DarkBee the html is being directly added to the render array in the build function... I see no twig file. Maybe I should have said dedicated theme file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I had used:

```
$build['content'] = ['#markup' => ' Add markup here ',];
```

I needed to use:

```
$build['content'] = ['#markup' => Markup::create(' Add markup here ',];
```

Thanks again for all the feedback everyone.